# Dúvida sobre onde colocar o script JS

Tags: javascript, html

Estou mexendo em um painel de um site na qual tem duas funções JS no fim da página que só serão utilizadas em uma página que será aberta em um modal.

Neste site também há um arquivo dedicado somente aos scripts.

Gostaria de saber se há algum problema eu colocar essas duas funções somente nesta página pois só utilizarei essas funções nela, ou eu tenho que SEMPRE colocar no arquivo .js independentemente se irei utilizar somente em uma página.

Pergunto pois falam sempre pra eu colocar todos os JS neste arquivo, entretanto, eu ACHO (não sei se é o correto) que não há necessidade de ficar poluindo mais e mais um arquivo colocando uma função que só utilizarei em uma página em todo o site.

Qual é a forma ideal?

Answer (score 1):

Renan, acho que tudo depende do bom senso. Qual o tamanho da aplicação etc. Se não quiser ter um JS com todas as funções, o que eu também não gosto, pode segmentar os arquivos JS de acordo com o sua área/domínio ou funcionalidades.

Answer (score 1):

Eu acredito que seja melhor um único arquivo bem minimizado do que uma nova requisição a cada vez que o usuário acessa uma página.

É a mesma coisa com o sass. Use um processador para facilitar os imports e crie um arquivo final minimizado com ele.

Gulp, grunt e etc, ajudam bastante.

Abs!